# How to update Vuejs2 page content when changing select option on api rxjs observable api endpoint?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, rxjs, vue-component

I'm a bit new at Vuejs2 and rxjs. So please be kind ^_^. I have an Observable api endpoint. I want to change the param value "food_type" via a select drop down on the same page. I want it so that when I select an item via the drop down the param value is updated, changing the end point and the data on the page gets reloaded. How can I achieve this?

here is my select drop down….

```
<div class="col-sm-2 divTableHead hand">
    <select name="food_type" id="food_type" class="form-control" v-model="food_type">
      <option value="" selected>Feeding</option>
      <option value=“A”>One</option>
      <option value=“AB”>Two Bee</option>
      <option value=“BB”>Bee Bee</option>
      <option value=“CB”>Cee Bee</option>
      <option value=“CC”>Cee Cee</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

here is what my Observable looks like…

```
data() {
  return {
    thisCat: [],
    food_type: ''
  }
},
subscriptions() {
  return {
    thisCat: Observable.from(axios.get(`${process.env.KITTY_URL}/api/v1/feedings/?cat__slug&cat__name=${this.$route.params.catName}&food_type=${""}`)
      .catch(error => console.log(error)))
      .pluck("data","results")
  }
},
```

Thank you -_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like what you're looking for is a [Watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers).

> This is most useful when you want to perform asynchronous or expensive
> operations in response to changing data.

That's exactly the case!

Check out the example below I prepared for you using the [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) API.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    postID: '',
    loading: false,
    postContent: null,
  },
  watch: {
    postID: function () {
      this.fetchPost()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchPost: function(id) {
      this.loading = true;
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/'+this.postID)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          this.postContent = {
            title: json.title,
            body: json.body
          }
          this.loading = false;
        })
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="postID">
      <option value="" disabled>Select a post</option>
      <option value="1">Post #1</option>
      <option value="2">Post #2</option>
      <option value="3">Post #3</option>
      <option value="4">Post #4</option>
      <option value="5">Post #5</option>
    </select>
    <h2 v-if="loading">Loading...</h2>
    <div v-if="postContent" class="post_content">
      <h3>{{postContent.title}}</h3>
      <p>{{postContent.body}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the watcher *watches* for any changes of that property and perform whatever you told it to do. In this case, call the `fetchPost` method and perform a fetch.

Comment: I solved it with slight modifications. But your illustration of the watcher helped out greatly. Since I used the watcher because of this...you get the win! THANK YOU SO MUCH -_^ ❤️❤️

Comment: Np, @Jessi! I'm glad I could help :D  Have fun learning Vue, it's an amazing front-end technology!